# Combine items in array based on property and maintain reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I have an array of items that I am creating a timeline out of. 
If 2 or more items are close together on the x axis (using the 'x' value') I want to combine them.

1. Loop through the array and compare the 'x' property. If they are close together then push the item into the 'instances' field of both items.
2. Change the date of both items to use the date of the first item.
3. Keep the original date in a field called 'idDate'
4. If an item is considered close to another item, make sure that item hasn't already been combined. If it has, use the 'x' property of the item it was combined with.
5. **In the code I created an array called 'desiredArray' to show what I want me output to be**

My current code pushes close items into the 'instances' array of the first close item but does not maintain the other items in the array. I also can't figure out how to do the date part. Any help is appreciated.

```js
const array = [{
    "date": "2017-03-04T13:30:00Z",
    "id": "7",
    "x": "-448.056888554414",
    "instances": [{
      "date": "2017-03-04T13:30:00Z",
      "id": "7",
      "x": "-448.056888554414"
    }]
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-08-13T13:30:00Z",
    "id": "11",
    "x": "25.521193637366817",
    "instances": [{
      "date": "2017-08-13T13:30:00Z",
      "id": "11",
      "x": "25.521193637366817"
    }]
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-08-15T13:30:00Z",
    "id": "12",
    "x": "31.296536103120246",
    "instances": [{
      "date": "2017-08-15T13:30:00Z",
      "id": "12",
      "x": "31.296536103120246"
    }]
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-08-20T13:30:00Z",
    "id": "13",
    "x": "39.95954980175038",
    "instances": [{
      "date": "2017-08-20T13:30:00Z",
      "id": "13",
      "x": "39.95954980175038"
    }]
  }
];

const newArray = [];
newArray.push({
  "date": "2018-08-06T13:30:00Z",
  "id": "14",
  "x": "639.95954980175038",
  "instances": [{
    "date": "2018-08-06T13:30:00Z",
    "id": "14",
    "x": "1054"
  }]
});

array.reverse().forEach((current: any) => {
  const last = newArray[newArray.length - 1];
  if (last.x - current.x < 40) {
    last.instances.push(current.instances[0]);
  } else {
    newArray.push(current);
  }
});

console.log(newArray);


// this is what I'm trying to create
const desiredArray = [{
    "date": "2018-08-06T13:30:00Z",
    "id": "14",
    "x": "639.95954980175038",
    "instances": [{
      "date": "2018-08-06T13:30:00Z",
      "id": "14",
      "x": "1054"
    }]
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-08-20T13:30:00Z",
    "idDate": "2017-08-20T13:30:00Z",
    "id": "13",
    "x": "39.95954980175038",
    "instances": [{
        "date": "2017-08-13T13:30:00Z",
        "id": "11",
        "x": "25.521193637366817"
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-08-15T13:30:00Z",
        "id": "12",
        "x": "31.296536103120246"
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-08-20T13:30:00Z",
        "id": "13",
        "x": "39.95954980175038"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-08-20T13:30:00Z",
    "idDate": "2017-08-15T13:30:00Z",
    "id": "12",
    "x": "31.296536103120246",
    "instances": [{
        "date": "2017-08-13T13:30:00Z",
        "id": "11",
        "x": "25.521193637366817"
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-08-15T13:30:00Z",
        "id": "12",
        "x": "31.296536103120246"
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-08-20T13:30:00Z",
        "id": "13",
        "x": "39.95954980175038"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-08-20T13:30:00Z",
    "idDate": "2017-08-13T13:30:00Z",
    "id": "11",
    "x": "25.521193637366817",
    "instances": [{
        "date": "2017-08-13T13:30:00Z",
        "id": "11",
        "x": "25.521193637366817"
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-08-15T13:30:00Z",
        "id": "12",
        "x": "31.296536103120246"
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-08-20T13:30:00Z",
        "id": "13",
        "x": "39.95954980175038"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-03-04T13:30:00Z",
    "idDate": "2017-03-04T13:30:00Z",
    "id": "7",
    "x": "-448.056888554414",
    "instances": [{
      "date": "2017-03-04T13:30:00Z",
      "id": "7",
      "x": "448.056888554414"
    }]
  }
]
```

Comment: There are so many duplicated values. It starts by parent that contains itself as instance while first item with same id contains different value (-448 vs 448)?

Comment: That was a mistake, I fixed it. It is much less repetitive in the real code but I tried to simplify for the example. In the actual app, the top level objects are used to draw the timeline and instances is used to make the tooltips.

Comment: What qualifies as "close together"?

Comment: In the code I have `last.x - current.x < 40`. That constitutes close together.